# UIApplication registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: not respecting absence of UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm calling UIApplication's registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: specifying only UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound. I am *not* specifying UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge.

My app's server, however, is sending an APNS notification payload that includes a "badge" key having a value of "1".

When the notification is received, my app's icon is badged with a red circled "1".

Even though the payload includes badge information, my expectation is that because I do not specify UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge, that iOS would not show a badge on my app's icon.

Could someone explain what the expected behavior is?

Thanks.

-Allan

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the OS shouldn't be displaying the badge unless your app has registered to receive that notification.

From the docs for **registerForRemoteNotificationTypes**:

> iOS does not display or play notification types specified in the notification payload that are not one of the requested ones. For example, if alert messages are not one of the accepted notification types, iOS does not display an alert even if one is specified in the notification payload.
>
> To find out what the application’s current notification types are, call the **enabledRemoteNotificationTypes** method.

Are you possibly using a token from a previous registration where the badge was specified?

Your payload server may be using a token which has the badge type registered.